# Javascript Event Bubbling Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling, event-propagation

Having a nightmare trying to figure out event Bubbling..

[Full test case](http://deanbayley.co.uk/test/event.html):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function $(ob) { return document.getElementById(ob) }

function bodyClick()
{
  $('win_clicks').value = parseInt($('win_clicks').value) + 1;
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(e)
{
  $('bl_lnk').addEventListener('click',function (e)
  {
    $('bl_lnk_clicks').value = parseInt($('bl_lnk_clicks').value) + 1;
  }, true);

  $('rd_lnk').addEventListener('click',function (e)
  {
    $('rd_lnk_clicks').value = parseInt($('rd_lnk_clicks').value) + 1;
  }, false);

}, false);
</script>
</head>

<body onclick="bodyClick();" style="font:16px Tahoma"> 

<div id="bl_lnk" style="position:absolute; width:250px; top:100px; left:50%; margin-left:-125px; padding:20px; background:#AAFFFF; border:1px solid #55AAFF; text-align:center; cursor:pointer">
  I'm a link, Click me! &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; and me!
</div>

<div id="rd_lnk" style="-moz-border-radius:40px; border-radius:50px; position:absolute; width:60px; height:40px; top:103px; left:50%; margin-left:77px; padding:5px; border:3px solid #FF6666; cursor:pointer"></div> 

<div style="position:absolute; width:250px; top:200px; left:50%; margin-left:-125px; padding:20px; background:#fff6bf; border:1px solid #FFD324;">
  <table cellspacing="10"> 
    <tr>
      <td>Blue Link Clicks:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="bl_lnk_clicks" value="0" style="width:35px; border:0; background:transparent" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red Link Clicks:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rd_lnk_clicks" value="0" style="width:35px; border:0; background:transparent" /></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>Body Clicks:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="win_clicks" value="0" style="width:35px; border:0; background:transparent" /></td>
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

From what I understand clicking in the area inside the red border should trigger all 3 event handlers (red, blue & body), only red and body are triggered..

I have tried altering the third value of `addEventListener` and changing the return values but to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: I won't swear to it without investing time I don't have into checking specs, but I believe events bubble through the DOM hierarchy, not through the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red div should be inside (structurally in your HTML, not visually) for the event to propagate to the blue div.